# Understanding of How to Create a Fluent Interface

Tags: c#, fluent, fluent-interface

Hi i'm trying to understand how i could build a readable and also error preventing Fluent-API without to much restriction for the User

to hold it simple let's say we want to change the following class to be fluent

```
public class Car
{
    public int Gallons { get; private set; }
    public int Tons { get; private set; }
    public int Bhp { get; private set; }
    public string Make { get; private set; }
    public string Model { get; private set; }

    public Car(string make, string model)
    {
        Make = make;
        Model = model;
    }

    public void WithHorsePower(int bhp)
    {
        Bhp = bhp;
        return this;
    }

    public void WithFuel(int gallons)
    {
        Gallons = gallons;
    }

    public void WithWeight(int tons)
    {
        Tons = tons;
    }

    public int Mpg()
    {
        return Gallons/Tons;
    }
}
```

the problem in this case the user should only be able to access `Mpg()` if `Weight()` and `Fuel()` got called first also the position of `HorsePower()` is irrelevant.

Samples:

```
int mpg =Car.Create().HorsePower().Fuel().Weight().Mpg();
int mpg =Car.Create().Fuel().HorsePower().Weight().Mpg();
int mpg =Car.Create().HorsePower().Fuel().HorsePower().Weight().Mpg();// <- no typo
int mpg =Car.Create().Fuel().Weight().HorsePower().Mpg();
int mpg =Car.Create().Weight().HorsePower().Fuel().Mpg();
int mpg =Car.Create().Weight().Fuel().Mpg();
```

Is there a easy way to do this without a big bunch of interfaces?
I also doesn't how to implement this nested interfaces in the right way

Here are the interfaces i currently created

```
interface Start
{
    IFuelWeight1 HorsePower();

    IHorsePowerWeight1 Fuel();

    IHorsePowerFuel1 Weight();
}

interface IFuelWeight1 // Start.HorsePower()
{
    IHorsePowerWeight1 Fuel();

    IHorsePowerFuel1 Weight();
}

interface IHorsePowerWeight1 // Start.Fuel()
{
    IHorsePowerWeight1 HorsePower();

    IHorsePowerFuelMpg Weight();
}

interface IHorsePowerFuel1 // Start.Weight()
{
    IHorsePowerFuel1 HorsePower();

    IHorsePowerWeightMpg Fuel();
}

#region End

interface IHorsePowerFuelMpg
{
    IFuelWeightMpg HorsePower();

    IHorsePowerWeightMpg Fuel();

    int Mpg();
}

interface IHorsePowerWeightMpg
{
    IFuelWeightMpg HorsePower();

    IHorsePowerFuelMpg Weight();

    int Mpg();
}

interface IFuelWeightMpg
{
    IHorsePowerWeightMpg Fuel();

    IHorsePowerFuelMpg Weight();

    int Mpg();
}

#endregion
```

---

**EDIT** for Adam Houldsworth :-)

- Is the Interface above a good one or is there a easier way to do this
  **but** hold the restriction for Mpg()?
- How to Implement the interface above to do this?:

  ```
      var k = myMiracle as Start;
      k.Fuel().Weight();
      k.Weight().Fuel();
      k.HorsePower().Fuel().Weight();
      k.HorsePower().Weight().Fuel();
      k.Fuel().HorsePower().Weight();
      k.Weight().HorsePower().Fuel();
  ```

Comment: Have you tried changing all of your `WithXXX` methods to return `Car` and simply `return this;` at the end of each method? Then you can `var car = new Car().WithFuel(100).WithMpg(35).WithHorsePower(200);`. Alternatively, just make these optional constructor arguments :-)

Comment: sure i know i can just return Car every time :) but unfortunately thats not the Point of my Question, also the optional Constructor will not help because it could also a Method which could do some crazy stuff ;) this Car Class is just an simple example of the problem

Comment: Sorry I thought the point of the question was to do this more easily than loads of interfaces, returning the item itself is straightforward. I would move away from buzzword implementations such as "fluent" and towards the standard and boring constructor parameters and standard methods.

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth could you explain why you wouldn't use fluent? because i want to refactor my whole MVVM App to use fluent because i thing it will be easier to add stuff and refator it later on, also see my edit :D

Comment: It's not that I wouldn't use it, but I think it only has limited scenarios where it works well. I've never needed to implement it specifically myself to improve the usage of a class or type.

Comment: mhh but for less experienced programmers this could help to understand the code more faster right? or dies is just add complexity to just look nicer from the outside ?

Comment: I personally think it can pollute a public interface if it isn't done carefully.

Comment: In this example, property initializers achieve your goal with no extra work and are more legible.
I can understand why you would want to do this. LINQ works very nicely with chaining - the difference is, LINQ creates a "nested" (in concept) object graph. This code simply assigns properties. Have you considered the LINQ route of writing extension methods?

Comment: I would also add that if it is invalid for a `Car` to be initialized without `Weight` or `Mpg` for example, then you *must* have those parameters as part of the constructor... otherwise you'll allow users to create a `Car` that's in an invalid state and there's no amount of "niceness" that a fluent-interface can offer to fix that (it's not worth the trade-off). Fluent interfaces can be useful, but in this particular case _you're doing it wrong_. Sorry!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One alternative could be to invoke all operations on Mpg() which will allow the other operations to be conditional.

This is already answered in SO with a code sample. Please refer to [Conditional Builder Method Chaining Fluent Interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10046629/conditional-builder-method-chaining-fluent-interface)

The post indicates, instead of Interfaces, the same might be achieved using constructors, with a calling method that makes all others operations conditional.

Answer (score 8):

Fluent API is a nice thing, but I would go a different way in your case. Building a car draws me more towards the [Builder pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern). That way you would hide a car being composed in a factory (not the factory method pattern) which accepts commands like you have now, but do not accept questions.

**No manufacturer lets you know details about their new car unless it is completed and prepared to be announced.** So you would have to send a command like `GetMyCar()` for releasing a car first and it would perfectly make sense that if you call `Mpg` on unfinished car you would get an exception. And it would still look good if you use that fluent pattern.

```
var builder = new CarBuilder();
// each building method returns `CarBuilder`
builder.BuildFrames(size).BuildChassis().AppendWheels(4)...
```

Ok, that's my opinion. However there are two more suggestions for your current situation you can choose from if you don't like the builder.

1) If user calls `Mpg` before `Weight` and `Fuel` are set, thrown an exception with a message explaining the situation. Also add a proper documentation of the `Mpg` method.

2) Make a constructor take all required parameters for other properties. This is, in my opinon, a better solution than the first one, because is states from the very start what you can expect.