# Call property after method in c#

Tags: c#

is it possible to call properties after methods?

**Example:**

```
public static class Test
{
    public static string Show { get; set; }

    public static void Get(string s)
    {
        Show = s;
    }
}
```

and call like this:

```
Test.Get("HI").Show;
```

Comment: What is your actual requirement? what is the type of `Show` what is type of `Test` ? Please be more clear while asking something

Comment: **Yes its possible** if you return an instance..

Comment: @un-lucky i edit my code in question

Comment: Why do you want to access a property after `Get` method? What scenario do you have?

Comment: @Shaharyar this is quite a standard usage for [fluent interface](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846811/understanding-of-how-to-create-a-fluent-interface) approach or just chaining methods (i.e. [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4) is good example for chaining of calls to setup mocks)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Very informative links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Update 2: A fluent interface**

If you are implementing a fluent interface, I would suggest renaming your methods as such:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Show { get; set; }

    public Test ConfigureShow(string show)
    {
        Show = show;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Your method is much more readable now and clearly defines the intent of the method:

```
var test = new Test()
    .ConfigureShow("HI");
```

Make the rest of the methods in your class follow the same pattern and chain your methods on new lines for improved readability.

**Update 1: What is your intent?**

Is there a particular reason that you are trying to do this? There are several issues with your class:

- Your methods should make sense - you should not have a method called `Get` which takes a parameter and then modifies the object. Generally `Get` methods imply that you are simply fetching something from the object.
- Why are you passing in a parameter to the method, only to fetch it again?
- Are you trying to implement a [Fluent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface#C.23) interface?

What is wrong with:

```
var show = "HI";
var test = new Test();
test.Show = show;
//You already have your text in the variable show, so why do you want to access it again?
```

**Original answer to OP's question**

```
public class Test
{
    public string Show { get; set; }

    public Test Get(string s)
    {
        Show = s;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Take a Look into the updates, `Test` is a static Class you cannot instantiate them

Comment: What OP is trying to do doesn't make any sense, you should ask and guide him properly rather than just throwing a code snippet with no logic.

Comment: Updated with a fluent interface along with advice about how to name methods